# Get URL string parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url

I have this URL in my database, in the "location" field:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

I can get it with `@object.location`, but how can I get the value of `v`? I mean, get `"xxxxxxxxxxxx"` from the URL string?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
require 'cgi'

# use URI.parse to parse the URL into its constituent parts - host, port, query string..
uri = URI.parse(@object.location)
# then use CGI.parse to parse the query string into a hash of names and values
uri_params = CGI.parse(uri.query)

uri_params['v'] # => ["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
```

Note that the return from `CGI.parse` is a `Hash` of `Strings` to `Arrays` so that it can handle multiple values for the same parameter name. For your example you would want `uri_params['v'][0]`.

Also note that the `Hash` returned by `CGI.parse` will return `[]` if the requested key is not found, therefore `uri_params['v'][0]` will return either the value or `nil` if the URL did not contain a `v` parameter.

Comment: You don't need to load `net/http` to get access to URI parsing. Just `require 'uri'` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ irb

irb(main):001:0> require 'cgi' => true
irb(main):002:0> test = CGI::parse('v=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx') => {"v"=>["xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]}
irb(main):003:0> puts test['v']
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
=> nil
```

Comment: That's what I was trying to think of.  I was looking in URI::HTTP and couldn't find any methods to parse the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Beyond using a library to parse the entire URL into protocol, hostname, path and parameters, you could use a simple regexp to extract the information.  Note that the regexp is a quick and dirty solution, and it'll fail if there's anything at all different about the URL, like if it has another parameter after the v parameter.

```
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
video_id = url.match(/\?v=(.+)$/)[1]
```

You can go further with what you did by using URI::parse to get the query information.

```
url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
video_id = CGI::parse(URI::parse(url).query)['v']
```